# sync online cannot be done with tableau online - Tableau Data Engine Error: 10000: Path does not exist

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

We are trying to publish a data source from a Tableau desktop version to tableau online and especially to synchronize the extraction, to have it run every 15mn.

We've managed to do only once.

Since that, we tried to publish other datasource and get them synchronized and every time, we faced the same error.

> Tableau Data Engine Error: 10000: Path does not exist.

Parsing Tableau's KB, we found the same issue [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/214926?start=0&tstart=0) but without any silver bullet...

We've tried the following

- Uninstall Tableau desktop
- Delete the remaining folders
- reboot the machine, on which Tableau is installed
- reinstall Tableau desktop
- Did all the publishing again

Not sure what else I can do...

Any tips are more than welcomed.

If it needs to be precised, we are doing the extract from a postgres database through tableau desktop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague figured out the answer.

On Tableau Desktop, you can use date as parameters on the SQL query.

However when you are trying to publish them on Tableau Online, the data source has some kind of glitch and is looking for something that it should not be looking, therefore creating the bug.

Putting the date in static with a date that goes back to 1980 with a filter, solve the issue.